# AppleScript to logoff Mac user after closing an application?

Tags: osx-lion, script, applescript, logout, logoff

I've configured a local user account on an iMac (Lion) to immediately launch Firefox to a specific page after logging in – the page contains a survey to be completed by the user.  This works fine.

What I want to do next but can't seem to figure out how is to automatically log off the user after they've completed the survey and they exit Firefox.

I don't want them to have to click the Apple icon at the top and then logout – when they finish the survey and exit Firefox, I'd like a script to execute that logs them out and takes the Mac back to the login screen for the next user.

Is it possible to associate a script and have it execute upon exiting an application?

Answer (score 0):

Save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.457047.plist` (or whatever you change the label to), and load it with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.superuser.457047.plist` or by logging out and back in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.superuser.457047</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>     
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application "System Events" to if (not (exists process "firefox")) or number of windows of process "firefox" is 0 then tell process "Finder" to click last menu item of menu 1 of menu bar 1</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>5</integer> <!-- run every 5 seconds -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

There's probably some cases where clicking the last menu item wouldn't work. `keystroke "q" using {option down, shift down, command down}` wouldn't work if the user was holding control.

`tell application "System Events" to log out` would show a confirmation dialog.

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/user.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend` doesn't show a confirmation dialog but keeps the user logged in and shows the fast user switching screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) can be configured to execute scripts when an application closes.